# Circuit shorting creates less resistance

Tags: circuit-analysis, current, circuit-design, resistance

Using only intuition, without mathematics, why can't the total resistance in the circuit of the 1st image be less than the total resistance in the 2nd image?

The 2nd circuit gives more path options for a current to flow, but I don't see why this could result in less resistance than the 1st circuit.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Suppose a is 0\$\Omega\$ and b is open. Or the opposite.

Comment: Arief, in the first case you have an infinite impedance between **P** and **Q** and in the second case that same path has zero impedance. Anything intuitive come from this recognition?

Comment: Maybe add some assumption like a and b are finite resistance ...

Comment: "The 2nd circuit gives more path option for a current to flow, but I don't see why this could result in less resistance than the 1st circuit" -- you have answered your question, intuitively, more 'path options' for current means less resistance.

Answer (score 2):

Without doing any actual calculations, consider an extreme case.

Let *a* be a small resistance, say 1 ohm. Let *b* be a large resistance, say 1M ohm.

In the first diagram, *a* becomes irrelevant, and we have two big resistors in parallel.

In the second diagram, *b* becomes irrelevant, and we have two small resistors in series.

*If we work it out, the first case gives 500k ohm, the second is 2 ohm.*

Answer (score 0):

What if a is lower resistance than b?  Assume a = 100 ohms and b = 1000 ohms. Do the calculations.

Now assume a = b = 100.

I think you'll find something interesting.

Comment: A book says "intuitively obvious that the resistance is the same or less than the 1st one", without mathematics.

Comment: You don't need math to assume one is lower than the other.  Think it through if a < b.  Then think it through it a = b.  Then think it through how impossible it might be that resistance increases of P and Q are connected.

Answer (score 0):

With the switch open, consider the voltages on P and Q.

Case 1 - Vp = Vq.

When the switch closes, no current flows through it. The conditions at A and B terminals are unaltered.

Case 2 - Vp ≠ Vq

When the switch closes, current flows, which extra current comes from the A and B terminals, and more current implies less resistance.

Answer (score 0):

Your intuition is correct, but for some reason you did not realize that if, in your words, there is "more path option for a current to flow", then that means the resistance *is* lower.  Ohm's law says, "less resistance; more current".

Answer (score 0):

Assuming resistance *a* >>> *b*

**Case 1**

[image]

The equivalent resistance *A-B* would be two '*a*' resistors in parallel.

**Case 2**

[image]

The equivalent resistance *A1-B1* would be two '*b*' resistors in series.

Hence resistance *A-B* would be greater than resistance *A1-B1* except in the case of *a* = *b* when both resistance *A-B* and *A1-B1* would be the same.